# Upload files from an iPad appliacation to SharePoint using objective C?

Tags: ipad, sharepoint, file-upload, base64, large-files

I have a requirement where user can upload files present in app to SharePoint via same app.

Is it possible to upload files using objective C? What should be the approach to upload (large) files to SharePoint?

Are there any Apple API's OR third party libraries to upload document?

**EDIT :**
I tried using http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CopyIntoItems method of sharepoint. But it needs file in base64 encoded format to be embeded into body of SOAP request . My code crashed on device when I tried to convert a 30 MB file in base64 encoded string? Same code executed just fine on simulator

Is there any other alernative to upload files (like file streaming etc) onto sharepoint??
I may have to upload files upto 500 MB? Is there more efficient library to convert NSData into base64 encoded string for large file???

Comment: You would be better putting that edit as a separate question - its specifically asking about algorithms to base64 encode large files and at this point has nothing to do with SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

You will be wanting to use [SharePoints Copy web service to upload a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy.copy%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Here are some examples of how to do it using C# [here](http://www.oriolardevol.com/Article/Details/3/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868/upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-through-the-built-in-web-services), an example of how to do it using [Objective c here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976329/sharepoint-copyintoitems-soap-message-in-objective-c), and here is an example of using [NTLM authentication with SharePoint web services from Objective C](http://www.robertkuzma.com/2011/07/making-a-post-in-objective-c-xcode-to-sharepoint-webservice-requiring-windows-ntlm-authenticaton-for-iphone-or-ipad/).

Putting that lot together is an exercise for the reader ;)

**Edit** - Maximum file sizes.

The default maximum file size for a document library is 50MB (2007/2010) but this can be increased up to 2GB ([see MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925083)) - however you are risking performance problems with a large volume of very large files.

Comment: Thanks for the links Ryan. Would it be a good approach to embed lage file data inside SOAP body and then upload it to sharepoint??

Comment: If its very large that could be a problem (and exactly how large depends upon many variables) but its exactly the same when uploading using the browser & not sure you have a choice of any other methods.

Comment: We may have to upload files upto 300 MB

Comment: 300 MB is very big for a doc library. See Edit

Comment: @krusty, did you have any success in putting together an app to upload a file to SharePoint?